# How to display only the last line of a listing ?

Tags: command-line, sed, awk, ls

Supposed I make a listing and sort the files by its temporal attribute:

```
ls -ltr

-rwxrwxrwx 1 bla bla 4096 Feb 01 20:10 foo1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bla bla 4096 Feb 01 20:12 foo2
.
.
.
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bla bla 4096 Mar 05 13:25 foo1000
```

What should I add behind the ls -ltr in a pipe chain in order to obtain only the last line of the listing ? I know there are sed and awk, but I do not know how to use them, I only know what they can do.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425), http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 29):

Since you asked about sed specifically,

```
ls -ltr | sed '$!d'
```

Comment: thank you, i am now a little proud having learned some concrete sed.

Comment: Also, `sed -n '$p'` does the same thing, but really `tail -1` is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 15):

You're looking for `tail` :

```
ls -ltr | tail -n 1
```

This will display only the last line of `ls -ltr`'s output. You can control the number of lines by changing the value after `-n`; if you omit `-n 1` entirely you'll get ten lines.

The benefit of using `tail` instead of `sed` is that `tail` starts at the end of the file until it reaches a newline, while `sed` would have to traverse the whole file until it reaches the end, and only then return the text since the last newline was found.

Comment: `tail -1` ... `-n` is redundant.

Comment: @Barry `tail -1` is deprecated (see the “RATIONALE” section of [the POSIX specification for `tail`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html), or the last part of [the GNU `tails` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html)); it still works in this case, for now, but it’s best to avoid using it in examples.

Answer (score 5):

With awk:

```
ls -ltr | awk 'END { print }'
```