# Is the AWK END behavior to keep the last line loaded in $0 in the man page?

Tags: awk

I read [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192762/173557) that describes how to use [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) to view the last line of output:

```
$ seq 42 | awk 'END { print }'
42
```

So it seems like when the `END` block is run the last line is loaded in `$0`.

This surprised me because the first line isn't loaded into the `BEGIN` block:

```
$ seq 42 | awk 'BEGIN { print }'
#=> blank
```

- Is this behavior documentation anywhere? (I searched through the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=awk&sektion=1) but didn't find anything)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `BEGIN` block is run before any input is processed, so `$0` hasn’t been initialised yet.

The `END` block doesn’t do anything to `$0`, which keeps its last value. In your AWK script, that’s just the last line read, because AWK reads all its input line by line, does its usual field-splitting processing (assigning `$0` and so on), but never finds a matching block; but for example

```
seq 42 | awk '{ $0 = "21" } END { print }'
```

outputs 21, not 42, so it’s not the case that “when the `END` block is run the last line is loaded in `$0`”.

This isn’t documented in the [`gawk(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) manpage, but it is documented in [`mawk(1)`](https://manpages.debian.org/mawk) (for that implementation of AWK obviously):

> Similarly, on entry to the `END` actions, `$0`, the fields and `NF` have their value unaltered from the last record.

The GNU AWK manual does [mention this behaviour](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND.html):

> In fact, all of BWK `awk`, `mawk`, and `gawk` preserve the value of `$0` for use in `END` rules.

“BWK `awk`” is Brian Kernighan’s `awk`, the [“one true `awk`”](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/); it implemented this behaviour in 2005, as documented in its `FIXES` file:

> Apr 24, 2005:
>           modified `lib.c` so that values of `$0` et al are preserved in the END
>           block, apparently as required by posix.  thanks to havard eidnes
>           for the report and code.

That change is visible in the [“one true `awk`” history](https://github.com/danfuzz/one-true-awk/commit/43fc55de6c2cfefa2e129e985f4b1960a448c645). The latest release of BWK `awk` behaves in the same way as GNU AWK:

```
$ echo three fields here | ./awk '{ $0 = "one" } END { print $0 " " NF }'
one 1
$ echo three fields here | ./awk 'END { $0 = "one"; print $0 " " NF }'
one 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Are you able to find references in the manual for that behaviour?

Comment: There are version of awk (nawk?) that will reset `$0` in the `END` block (IIRC).

Comment: @mbigras I can’t find any reference to `END` v. `$0` processing in [Dougherty and Robbins’ *sed & awk*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do); I don’t have the original AWK book to check that. I’ll look through the GNU AWK documentation...

Comment: @mbigras It turns out `mawk`’s manpage mentions this, as does the GNU AWK documentation (which ilkkachu had already [quoted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356447/86440)).

Answer (score 4):

According to the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND.html#I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND), it's slightly unclear what `$0` should contain in an END rule. POSIX demands that `NF` *"shall retain [its] value"*<sub>(*)</sub>, but doesn't mention `$0`.

> Most probably due to an oversight, the standard does not say that `$0` is also preserved, although logically one would think that it should be. In fact, all of BWK awk, mawk, and gawk preserve the value of `$0` for use in `END` rules. Be aware, however, that some other implementations and many older versions of Unix awk do not.

In a sense, I find this behaviour logical. Leaving `$0` for the `END` block allows for easy access to the last record, if necessary. The first record is easy to access with `NR == 1 {...}` so doesn't need a special keyword. On the other hand, executing  `BEGIN` blocks before loading the first record allows setting `FS` or `RS` in time for them to be active for the first record.

<sup>(* Whatever that means, see comments.)</sup>

Comment: POSIX [says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) “Inside an **END** action, **NF** shall retain the value it had for the last record read”, which might be subject to interpretation. GNU AWK at least just keeps the value from the end of the last block that was processed; `seq 42 | awk '{ $0 = "2 1" } END { print NF }'` outputs “2”.

Comment: @StephenKitt, well, yes... assigning to $0 updates NF, so I'm not sure what the difference here is.

Comment: When you say “POSIX demands that `NF` contain the number of fields in the last record”, I understand that as meaning that `NF` must contain the number of fields in the last record as it was read, not the number of fields in the last value assigned to `$0`. The same applies for POSIX, even more so since “read” is explicit: does it mean the value assigned when the last record was read, or the value `NF` had when the last record was finished processing?

Comment: `echo three fields here | awk '{ $0 = "one" } END { print $0 " " NF }' #=> one 3` seems like `NF` doesn't get recalculated

Comment: @mbigras What version of AWK are you using? `gawk` prints “one 1” on my system.

Comment: You could just about argue that in the case of `$0 = "1 2 3"` the line was _read_ from a string. Maybe. Possibly. At a pinch. Weasel words perhaps?

Comment: The awk that came with my Mac (`awk version 20070501` whatever the origin) has curious behaviour, it seems to recalculate `NF` only if it's referenced on the record `$0` was changed.  `echo three fields here | awk '{$0 = "one"} END {print $0 " " NF}'` gives `one 3`, but `| awk '{$0 = "one"; NF} END {print $0 " " NF}'` gives `one 1`... gawk and mawk on Debian give a `1` in all situations.

Comment: @roaima, well, the description of NF says that it "shall _retain_ the value it had", which would to me imply 'remaining the same' or 'not changing'. One hopes that if the intended meaning was 'shall be reset to the value it had at point X' they would have chosen another word to use.

Comment: @ikkachu, yes I'm with you on this one. It feels to me that POSIX may have unintentionally misdefined the behaviour of `$0` in an `END` block. (But who am I to say.)

Comment: @StephenKitt `awk version 20070501` on macOS `10.12.3`