# AWK simple program is behaving differently than expected when find max number of occurences of a value

Tags: awk

I have a simple awk program ip.awk to find the highest occurrence of an ip address in a log file. IP addresses are in the first column:

```
$cat ip.awk

{ ip[$1]++ }
END {
for (i in ip)
        if ( max < ip[i] ) {
                max = ip[i]
                maxnumber = i }
print maxnumber, " has accessed ", max, " times.", " $1 is: ", $1 }
```

And I am using it to parse a file access.log, a few sample entries from which are shown below:

```
173.13.151.14 - - [11/Sep/2014:23:57:53 +0100] "GET /wp/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 7404 "http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=2407" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
173.13.151.14 - - [11/Sep/2014:23:57:53 +0100] "GET /wp/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/navigation.js?ver=20140711 HTTP/1.1" 200 1720 "http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=2407" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
173.13.151.14 - - [11/Sep/2014:23:57:53 +0100] "GET /wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/tailshadow.png HTTP/1.1" 200 11433 "http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=2407" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
173.13.151.14 - - [11/Sep/2014:23:57:53 +0100] "GET /wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cropped-wp3.png HTTP/1.1" 200 65326 "http://theurbanpenguin.com/wp/?p=2407" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
173.13.151.14 - - [11/Sep/2014:23:57:53 +0100] "GET /wp/?p=2407 HTTP/1.1" 200 21717 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
```

The awk script, rightly gives, I believe,:

```
$awk -f ip.awk access.log 
68.107.81.110  has accessed  311  times.  $1 is:  70.168.57.66
```

My confusion is in the value of $1, which from what I understand, should be changed line-by-line to the value in the first column of the line as awk moves through the log file access.log.

This checks out from the check that I added at the end of the program ( "$1 is: ", $1" ), as this gives back the ip address of the last line ( the log files is 30000+ lines so I made a program to check that this script was actually working:

```
$cat testfile.log 
1   apple
2   banana
2   banana
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5   flerb
5   flerb
5   flerb
5   flerb
5   flerb , green - tea
6
7
8   grapes 0 and some more filler to make a long line
9
```

But when I do this I get, the right answer, but don't get "9" for the value of $1 when I print it out. What am I missing?

```
$awk -f ip.awk testfile.log 
5  has accessed  6  times.  $1 is:
```

Attempting to eliminate another variable I awked the first column of ip addresses alone to a new file and ran ip.awk on it, and got the exact same results as when I run ip.awk on the full log file, as expected. I also feel like I'm missing something fundamental because how is a dotted-decimal ip address being used with an array?
Also: if I use 1.0 2.0... for 1 2... I still get the correct answer but still no $1 value.

Answer:
As thecarpy suggested, the problem was that when entering values in my testfile I hit enter after the last value, adding a superfluous newline which set $1 to an empty string when it parsed that line.

Comment: I am unable to replicate your results.  Given your `awk` script and input file, my output is: `5  has accessed  6  times.  $1 is:  9`.

Comment: That's odd, I've ran it and few times and just ran it again to be sure, I still get the same result.

Comment: Would you not have a superfluous newline at the end, sorry, silly question, but I cannot reproduce either ... I have GNU Awk 4.1.4

Comment: That was it, a superfluous newline at the end. Not a silly question at all apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an `awk` program the `END` block is run when you have read all the data, so there is no input line to parse. (You might find that some implementations of `awk` leave `$1` as the first field of the last line. See [Is the AWK END behavior to keep the last line loaded in $0 in the man page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356444/is-the-awk-end-behavior-to-keep-the-last-line-loaded-in-0-in-the-man-page/356446).)

`awk` uses associative arrays. This means you can use any string as the index. Numeric arrays work because `a[1]` is the array `a[]` subscripted by the string that happens to be the single character `1`. It could equally be `a[one]` or even `a[banana]`. The dotted quad for your IP address is just a string.