# tree command to only output file and directory count?

Tags: tree

I want to keep only the last line of `tree`'s output or the file+directory count report. Preferably, with the `-a` switch.

An example output I desire:

```
585 directories, 37722 files
```

Is this possible with `tree`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display only the last line of a listing ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192760/how-to-display-only-the-last-line-of-a-listing)

Comment: @phuclv it does, but I'm looking to see if there's any combination of flags for `tree` that would skip listing. That would take some time if a directory is big.

Comment: that'll need a different command and the question should be `command to output file and directory count` instead of *tree command to only output file and directory count?*. It's very simple to count in awk or perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tail` is a standard filter to print last line(s)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html). To print one last line use `tail -n 1`.

```
tree -a | tail -n 1
```

Comment: Isn't there any combination of flags for `tree` that would do the same?